# Insert Python string to datetime Oracle column

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, executemany

I have a python list with 10 string fields.
One of the strings is a date and I want to write the list to an Oracle table.

I try to use `executemany`.
if I write all fields as strings it is OK but when I try to convert one of the fields to a date and change the table column type to `DATE` I get errors.

For example:

I try to change from my list (data) the field to datetime

```py
data[0][2] = datetime.strptime(data[1][2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

and then I try to `executemany` and I got the error:

> ```
> TypeError: expecting date or datetime
> ```

Maybe someone can share example or idea to solve this issue?

sample data:

[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxVyh.jpg)

and after that i try to executemany like that:

```
sql="insert into py_table (RECORD_DATE,TYPECOL,GMTRD) values (:1,:2,:3)"
cursor.executemany(sql, listdf)
connection_dev.commit()
```

Comment: With `data[0][2] = datetime.strptime(data[1][2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")` you read from the array index `1` and assign to the array index `0`. Have you tried updating all the rows in the array and using the correct indexes?

Comment: If that does not work then please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a minimal python script that we can execute (not just a single line snippet); the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the complete error message for that script; and the expected output.

Comment: Thank you MT0 , i add some info ' hope it  make easy to understand what the problem. now the error is ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number